# User email being deleted when submitting Profile 2 form

Tags: forms, users, debugging

i'm debugging a site that I haven't made.  The issue is that the users email address is being deleted.

I've found which form it's happening on; and by using hook_form_FORM_ID_alter I can see that $form has this information at before sending and not after it's been sent.

I've written a patch that writes it back in but my question is what the best way is to backtrace where the bug actually is.  I'm using phpstorm as my IDE and have put breakpoints in modules I think could be at fault but without joy.

Any other tips on this one ?

Much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to check that **hook_form_FORM_ID_alter**  and the **callbacks** inside that hook, at least at the end you can check if the **$form** still have all the previously data

Answer (score 0):

Just to clarify the answer from DarkteK.

In the code multi versions of hook_form_FORM_ID_alter where being run.  Its this I needed to search for.

Thanks.

Comment: Glad it worked for you :)